# Creating app lock for android phone

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create an  android activity "Save_Password" which stores the password in a database "PasswordDB".There is another activity named "Enter_Password" in which I want to allow the user to only enter the password which is already stored in SQLite database.

When I run this for the first time "Save_Password" should open. When I again open it "Enter_Password" should open.

Is there some query which I can execute to check if table exist or not.
Or should I use Shared preferences?

Comment: If this is a network based application,means you stored your data like user info in the network then you have to fetch the info first after checking any user present then show Enter Password option otherwise Save Password.@Shreya

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a database for just storing a "password". You can use **SharedPreferences** for that purpose.

Its very simple to use and a much light-weight operation that database. Doesn't slow down your app even by a bit.

If you are storing passwords locally in SharedPreferences, then they can be easily read, so its better to encrypt them and store and later decrypt them.

You can do this in a very simple way by using this small library, [SecurePreferences](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences)

It will handle all the encryption and decryption automatically for you.

Comment: Is your problem resolved or you need more help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save password right? Then use SharedPreferences. 
But saving password locally is not a good design choice.At least encrypt the data before you store, and decrypt it whenever you want to read it.